# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

Recently I had tried adding the google_mobile_ads package to my flutter app.  After deciding I didn't want them anymore I took them away, only to run into this error.  Prior to the package, everything worked fine, but now I can't even run the project anymore.  This is what Xcode tells me:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/13XrC2NTgQ87hlVCmLI2qiQTLhhD6vgMaQkz0ac_tQM0/edit?usp=sharing

What I've tried:

Flutter clean

Restarting Mac

Restarting Xcode and IDE

Changing simulators

Deleting iOS folder completely and rebuilding it

Any direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you running M1 or Intel?

Comment: You could try deleting the `DerivedData` folder from Xcode [Apple](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deva52afe8a4).  Alternatively I've found `arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi` helped fix my own CocoaPods issues on M1 [Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Developing-with-Flutter-on-Apple-Silicon).